# Flutter: possible to wait for sibling widgets to finish building?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The title probably says it all. My scenario is that I have different widgets waiting for firebase data to build their contents. The last widget should wait for others to complete and do some computation based on the retrieved data from Firebase. Is this possible at all?

I have tried ValueListenableBuilder which gave me this error:

The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for ValueNotifier:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Comment: this is because you want to do something inside `build` method - this is wrong as `build` can be called multiple times and you cannot control that - if you have some data layer that uses `Future` / `Stream` use their API to find out when your data is ready and execute your code there

Comment: Totally agrees with @pskink. i also face same issue recently and i solved it but building another async method. in that method i wait for 1 micro second, so build method complete and the i change data and call setState.

Comment: Is it possible to add a Future in your method instead of waiting for 1 micro second? I always consider it unsafe (or waste) to wait for a fixed period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `build` method use the `FutureBuilder` widget which is used for operations. The `FutureBuilder` widget contains a property called `future` which takes a method that returns a `future`.

Inside that method you can execute the first query using `await` and use the result of the first query to execute the second query.

Comment: Thanks. Following your approach, I successfully build it. Essentially, I put nested Firebase accesses within a future method, wait for the method before building the context.